# How to get access to Developer: Inspect TM Scopes data?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am making an extension to identify and display various language syntax features (keywords, functions, macros etc.) TM Scopes window already does that (see the attached image). Is there a way to access this data (via some api call) so that I can build my extension on top of it?

[image]

Comment: I already answered this question before (see link above), and the answer is basically: no, you'd have to tokenize the file again yourself to get the info.

Comment: I understand. The scope-info extension is broken for the current version of VSCode and hence, doesn't work. I am hoping to find a way to hook to TM Scopes code and get the data.

Comment: VSCode doesn't let you hook into arbitrary UI elements, the only interaction allowed is via the strictly defined extension API. Regarding scope-info - I didn't know it has issues with current versions. Both VSCode and scope-info use the vscode-textmate NPM module you could use to tokenize the file yourself: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-textmate